# GoldenDict Chinese-Chinese Dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

I have an intermediate grasp of mandarin and would like a Chinese-Chinese dictionary.  One where I input Chinese characters and it returns me a Chinese definition.
I am using GoldenDict and have tried to find one like it with no luck.  All I find is other language-Chinese or Chinese-other language dictionaries.
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: this seems hard to understand，googling 汉语词典 will yield a number of such dictionaries

Comment: zdic.net is Chinese, try it!

Comment: I know of zdic.net.  I need specific files that are used by GoldenDict so I can lookup words offline.

Comment: For traditional Chinese, I recommend `萌典`, available on android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Lingoes for a long time, and I also use GoldenDict on my android cellphone.

The beauty of GoldenDict is that it supports a lot dictionary formats, and lingoes format is one of them.

You can download 高级汉语大词典 here, and add it to the GoldenDict folder.

http://www.lingoes.cn/download/dict/ld2/Advanced%20Chinese%20Big%20Dictionary.ld2

Answer (score 0):

You can access many authoritative dictionaries here:

新华字典，康熙字典，说文解字，书法字典，词语字典，成语词典

http://tool.httpcn.com/Zi

For beginners, you may find this one useful and easy to understand:

http://zd.chinesehelper.cn

I also want to mention some online dictionaries from Taiwan, which I used before those from mainland China are available online.

http://www.spps.tp.edu.tw/dict.htm

Comment: This is a better Taiwanese dictionary: https://www.moedict.tw/

Answer (score 0):

[高级汉语大词典](http://vdisk.weibo.com/s/B_bStAhCUdVo-)

The file name says that it is a *stardict* but it's compatible with GoldenDict.

It's not very comprehensive but the entries are rather extensive.

Here's an example:

> **劣**
>
> liè
>
> 〈动〉
>
> (1)
>
> 认为不好 [have a low opinion of; think lowly of] 以为不及 [inferior]
>   成以其小,劣之。――《聊斋志异·促织》
>
> (2)
>   劣下(低能;低下);劣弟(在平辈或朋友间表示自谦的称呼);劣丈(在世交中,长辈对晚辈表示自谦的称呼)
>
> (3)
>   顽皮;乖巧 [naughty]。如:劣相(乖僻);劣角(乖劣,顽皮);劣缺(乖戾,狠毒,顽劣)
>
> (4)
>   强;美 [strong;fine]
>   论着雄心力劣牙爪,今日也合消,也合消封妻荫子,禄重官高。――元·尚仲贤《三夺槊》
>
> (5)
>   暴烈,不驯服 [viollent]。如:劣性(暴烈性格);劣彆(倔强;固执)
>
> liè
>
> 〈形〉
>
> (1)
>   (会意。从力,从少。这是合并两个字的意思而构成的会意字。本义:弱;小)
>
> (2)
>   同本义 [weak;small]
>   劣,弱也。――《说文》
>   寿命长短,骨体强劣,各有人焉。――曹植《辩道论》
>
> (3)
>   又如:劣马(瘦弱的马;又指烈性马);劣弱(衰弱;懦弱)
>
> (4)
>   少,不足 [few]
>   夫德劣故用兵,犯法故施刑。――《论衡》
>
> (5)
>   不好;低劣,与“优”相对 [bad; evil]
>   优劣异名。――《论衡·气寿》
>   必能使行阵和睦,优劣得所。――诸葛亮《出师表》
>   羸牛劣马。――《齐民要术·养牛马》
>
> (6)
>   又如:劣性(恶劣的品性);劣缺(不好,恶劣);劣衿(品行恶劣的生员)

Comment: An online dictionary would be better.

Comment: @user3678473 OP asked for a GoldenDict dictionary, why don't you get him to change his question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest an online dictionary to you (it also has an offline version which can be used with GoldenDict and be found in pdawiki, a famous Chinese Mdict forum), for example:

http://www.guoxuedashi.net/hydcd/106017o.html

The most important advantage of the website is that you can browse the corresponding page in the photocopy of the dictionary（汉语大词典）.

The reason is that the dictionary is originally written in traditional Chinese and the simplified version is (both online and offline) just transformed.

BTW, 词典 is different from 字典. 词典 contains the definition of words, and 字典 contains the definition of characters. I think 词典 is more suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

for chinese-chinese dictionary, the 國語辭典 (from taiwan, in traditional chinese) is second to none:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cbdic/search.htm

the best is that, together with "國語辭典簡編本", "國語小字典" & "成語典"; you may download them here:

http://resources.publicense.moe.edu.tw/index.html

if you know unix commands, it's an easy job to modify the source files to a plain text file, or database, and save in your computer.

another one, as essence as 國語辭典, is the 漢語多功能字庫 (from hong kong, in traditional chinese, with chinese/english interface):

http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/

the description is:
Multi-function Chinese Character Database:
With Archaic Script Forms,
Etymologies,
English-Chinese Lookup,
& Word-formations Phonologically Disambiguated
According to the Cantonese Dialect

then, the internet archive has the famous 康熙字典 (from 四庫全書, version for emperor 乾隆)

[https://archive.org/search.php?query=御定康熙字典&and[]=subject%3A%22四庫全書薈要%22&and[]=creator%3A%22（清）康熙聖祖仁皇帝%22](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%E5%BE%A1%E5%AE%9A%E5%BA%B7%E7%86%99%E5%AD%97%E5%85%B8&and[]=subject%3A%22%E5%9B%9B%E5%BA%AB%E5%85%A8%E6%9B%B8%E8%96%88%E8%A6%81%22&and[]=creator%3A%22%EF%BC%88%E6%B8%85%EF%BC%89%E5%BA%B7%E7%86%99%E8%81%96%E7%A5%96%E4%BB%81%E7%9A%87%E5%B8%9D%22)

need any more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

GoldenDict can support StarDict dictionary file format, you can find many StarDict dictionary files from [HuZheng's site](http://download.huzheng.org/zh_CN/), as you may know, HuZheng (胡正) is the developer of StarDict.

You can download 新华字典, 高级汉语大词典, and 现代汉语词典.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you 现代汉语词典. As it is an intermediate level dictionary which is not too complicated to confuse you, but it covers words commonly used.